# ng-show on basis of Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the [AngularSlideables](https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables) to smoothly expand and collapse an area where people can find more details with the following code ([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3sVz8/19/)):

```
<h3 slide-toggle="#details" >More details</h3>
<div id="details" class="slideable">
    <p>Bespoke aesthetic Bushwick craft beer. Qui aesthetic butcher, cardigan ex scenester Neutra American Apparel mumblecore.</p>
</div>
```

This works fine, but when the details area is expanded I want `More details` to be changed to `Less details` (and a minus-icon) so that it is clear that you can click again to change back.

Normally I would do something like this using an `ng-show="some expression"`, but I don't see what kind of expression I can use here to know whether it is expanded or not.

Does anybody know how I can change the `Mode details` to `Less details` with this AngularSlideables-directive? All tips are welcome!

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like:

html:

> ```
> <h1 slide-toggle="#derp" slide-toggle-on="Less" slide-toggle-off="More" >More</h1>
> ```

That way you can add any message to 'more' or 'less'.

js:

```
...
.directive('slideToggle', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var target = document.querySelector(attrs.slideToggle);
        var messageOn = attrs.slideToggleOn;
        var messageOff =  attrs.slideToggleOff;

        attrs.expanded = false;
        element.bind('click', function() {

            var content = target.querySelector('.slideable_content');
            if(!attrs.expanded) {
                element.html(messageOn);
                content.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                var y = content.clientHeight;
                content.style.border = 0;
                target.style.height = y + 'px';
            } else {
                element.html(messageOff);
                target.style.height = '0px';
            }
            attrs.expanded = !attrs.expanded;
        });
    }
}
```

});
    ...

Get the new attributes is:

> var messageOn = attrs.slideToggleOn;
>
> var messageOff =  attrs.slideToggleOff;

To apply use:

> element.html(messageOn);//not expanded;
>
> element.html(messageOff);//already expanded;

Comment: Tell me if it works, I already tested on your Fiddle. @kramer65

Comment: Hi Alvaro. I haven't tried it yet, mainly because it looks like a lot of code for such a simple thing plus I don't really understand it. I now thought of solving it by simply setting a model to true when clicking the slide-toggle element, and setting it to false when clicking it again. On that basis I then set the text to "More details" or "Less details". What do you think of that solution?

Comment: element.html("More"); and  element.html("Less");  it's a single line. and most fast way to achieve your goal. Using a ng-model you will see few issues, I already tried, Than made this change that I showing to you.

Comment: But this website needs to multi-lingual, which means I can't depend on what it says in the text.

Comment: In that case, you can add more custom attr to you directive to customize the solution making it more elegant. Will update the answer

Comment: Please try this new approach and judge if it good enough to be marked as correct answer.@kramer65

Comment: @kramer65 please try this way. I think it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the source code a little bit to expose the toggle status. This is a little bit awkward but it works.

```
 restrict: 'A',
 scope : {
       expanded : "=expanded"
 },
```

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/stealop/y6zfzvpq/1/)

Comment: Looks good. But won't this make trouble when I have several expansion parts in one page/controller?

Comment: I updated the link now. I think we can just use the variable  in the isolated scope that is created by the directive. So we dont have to worry about multiple expansion

Answer (score -1):

AngularSlideables is working by manipulating the height of the `<div>`. You *could* key a model to the height of said div. So in your example, it could be captured as `$('#derp').getBoundingClientRect().height` – `===0` shows "more" `>0` shows "less".

YMMV here. In a perfect world, AngularSlideables would provide an API to query this state (setting a data value on the element, perhaps.) Unless you want to add that to AngularSlideables, this solution could work.

Comment: I don't think that's the best practice.